# fill containers with blocks of different sizes to have containers of "similar" sizes

Tags: algorithms

I have a sorted list of blocks `L` that I want to put in 4 containers `C`, the containers have a size limit `S`. I want to have similar containers height, by similar I mean the size variance should be as small as possible.

eg:

```
S = 4
L = [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

should result in:

```
C = [[1, 1], [3], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

note: it is always possible to put every blocks inside the 4 containers and I can't change blocks order

is there a way to do this efficiently? I couldn't find algorithm names about this but I didn't really know how to search for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a generalization of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) (select elements of a set so that their sum is exactly `n`). You want to select *four* subsets of elements so that the sum of each subset is `n` (where `n` is 1/4 of the sum of all blocks), so it's a harder variant of the standard problem.

Unfortunately, the knapsack problem is known to be NP-complete, i.e. practically unsolvable for large `n`. However, there is a rich literature about *approximate* solutions, which is what you want.

Comment: I will look into knapsack algorithms. there is stilla difference with your response, as in my exemple, there is not always an option for each containers to have the exact same size